# Can a Bitcoin wallet be identified as belonging to an exchange?

Tags: exchanges, privacy

Ethereum wallets can be associated with Exchanges (e.g. Etherscan.io will tell you if an address is a Poloniex one).

Is this possible for Bitcoin addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in theory is possible to guess the ownership of an address to an Exchange.

Notice that I said *in theory* and I also mentioned that it's a *guess*. That's because per design each address is anonymous. However, since the blockchain is public, you can analyze the type and amount of transactions getting in and out a specific address and make assumptions based on patterns.

An exchange has generally a large amount of transactions. If they use a finite amount of addresses, eventually transactions will reuse existing addresses.

If you provide a tool or a way for people to publicly share/associate specific addresses with Exchanges, then eventually you will build an archive of matches. I believe this is what Etherscan does.

Comment: *If they use a finite amount of addresses, eventually transactions will reuse existing addresses.* That's mathematically true, but the number of possible addresses is so large that reuse will not happen before the sun goes out.  In practice an exchange will never reuse a deposit address, and so the technique you describe will not be useful.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's not quite true. Many exchanges will provide one address to a user, leading to eventual reuse if the user makes multiple deposits. It is possible to identify the random address->desposit address->exchange hot/cold wallet trail given enough data points.